Use Jenkins credentials in Python script withEnv
I have the following code where I define environmental variables and use them in python script:
groovy script:
withEnv(["USERNAME=${username}",
         "PASSWORD=${password}",
         "CERTIFICATE=/path/to/cert.pem"]) {
    email = sh(script: "python3.9 -u get_email.py")
}

get_email.py
import os

username = os.environ['USERNAME']
password = os.environ['PASSWORD']
certificate = os.environ['CERTIFICATE']
#some logic

I get the error:
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'USERNAME'

What am I doing wrong?
I found this solution and it works. However, I don't like that export statements are printed in the Jenkins log like this:
+ export USERNAME=test-user
USERNAME=test-user


Where are your ${username} and ${password} defined? I suppose that the reason why the mentioned solution works is not because the variable is exported - it's because you should use withCredentials wrapper to retrieve the credentials and map them to environment variables, not withEnv. My assumption is that your username and password are in fact null.

What @alexander-pletnev said, looks like the groovy variables are null. Using withEnv should work, but withCredentials is more appropriate
